# Mezuzah on window

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, architecture-design

Many homes have a porch over the first level which is only accessible by going out and back in through a window on the second level. Would this window/doorway require a mezuzah? Is there something about a window that precludes it from being considered a door as far as hilchos mezuzah goes?

(I am ignoring all arguments about porches and access to the street in this question. Let us assume the opinion that a door in this situation would in fact require a mezuzah)

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're talking about. Could you maybe add an image or link?

Comment: @Scimonster the access to this porch looks like it's a window. If it's not, pretend it is:) http://images-68.har.com/e1/mediadisplay/68/hr3295868-1.jpg

Comment: Looks like a glass door to me.

Comment: @Scimonster then pretend

Comment: Are you ignoring the Rambam's requirement that the room have a roof, and be fit to live in, and be fit to live honorably in?

Comment: @Ze'ev yes because an area that is not supposed to have a roof, like a yard or a city (or a porch) are not limited by his words. At least this is the way the achronim (taz?)  have addressed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oholai Shaim 40](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48802&st=&pgnum=162) quoting Daas Kedoshim Yore Deiah 289:10 says that a window even if used as an entry way does not require a Mezuza. However he says that if it is made for the purpose of an entrance then it would require a Mezuza.

Mikdash Me'at 15 disagrees and holds it almost never would require a Mezuza.

Comment: Isnot there a minimum height of a door for a mezuza

Comment: @Hazoriz The minimum is only ten tephachim (Yo'd 287) so that would not exclude the average window.

Comment: @user6591 Are you counting the open part or the part that lets the light in, I do not usually see windows that have 10 teffohim openings

Comment: @Hazoriz any part that moves ie the sash and panes Is what I am considering. Casement windows especially are tall. But ignoring all this, only the Rambam requires a proper door in order to necessitate a mezuzah, and although we take his opinion into consideration lichumra and try to only make Brachos on frames with doors, we do put mezuzahs on doorless frames, so as we would need to consider is the opening. There is a possibly related argument if a large piece of furniture blocks a doorway whether that obviate the need for a mezuzah, but a) I'm trying to avoid these types of arguments, and

Comment: @ b) I think standard practice is to have a mezuzah in those situations and c) a window is definitely not going to passul a passageway like a bookcase might.