# Mezuzah for windows that look like doors?

Tags: mezuzah

I have 2 windows in my new apartment that look like french doors but you can't walk through them.... They are 20' in the air.

Right up to them having french doors, I'd say it's a window and doesn't require a mezuzah.... But once you add actual doors, I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Welcome home!

Comment: Isn't a door something that's made to go through for entering and exiting?

Comment: @Chatzkel what if someone likes jumping out of windows to get around?

Comment: @yaynkileh good point, but the OP says "but you can't walk through them"

Comment: @Chatzkel what about jumping through them?

Comment: @yaynkileh I've never seen anyone put a mezuza in a window. See this question for further sources https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62673/mezuzah-on-window

Comment: is this asking for a practical psak?

Comment: Is is for practical application....  It looks like two sets of french doors (glass) but they don't go anywhere..... Perhaps there was a balcony once?

Comment: Chatzkel, i had already seen the post and it actually complicates the question.                                         Oholai Shaim 40 quoting Daas Kedoshim Yore Deiah 289:10 says that a window even if used as an entry way does not require a Mezuza. However he says that if it is made for the purpose of an entrance then it would require a Mezuza.

Mikdash Me'at 15 disagrees and holds it almost never would require a MMezuza.  It is not clearly a window but much more like a door.

Comment: @Ruvain you mean to say that maybe it was constructed as a door and is no longer used as such and therefore might be different?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/225406/jewish/Which-Rooms-Require-a-Mezuzah.htm. no source given - What if I never use that door?

Unused doors that are sealed closed (doors actually nailed to the door frame) are exempt from mezuzahs. An entrance that is blocked by furniture or a door that is usually kept locked requires a mezuzah.

Comment: For questions like these, a picture is incredibly helpful for those who haven't yet been at your place